# OpenGL glDrawArrays not drawing arrays

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I am looking at [this tutorial](https://github.com/SilverTiger/lwjgl3-tutorial/tree/master/src/silvertiger/tutorial/lwjgl) and looking at the code for some reason their arrays draw to the screen (I tested it) but my slightly edited code doesn't draw anything to the screen.

Here's the GitHub: https://github.com/BigBadE/GLHelp

Here's the relevant code:

This is called to draw everything:

```
private void drawTextureRegion(float x1, float y1, float x2, float y2, float s1, float t1, float s2, float t2, Color c) {
    if (vertices.remaining() < 8*6) {
        /* We need more space in the buffer, so flush it */
        flush();
    }

    float r = c.getRed();
    float g = c.getGreen();
    float b = c.getBlue();
    float a = c.getAlpha();

    vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
    vertices.put(x1).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t2);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);

    vertices.put(x1).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s1).put(t1);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y2).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t2);
    vertices.put(x2).put(y1).put(r).put(g).put(b).put(a).put(s2).put(t1);

    numVertices += 6;

    flush();
}
```

Flush method:

```
private void flush() {
    if (numVertices > 0) {
        vertices.flip();

        if (vao != null) {
            vao.bind();
        } else {
            vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
            specifyVertexAttributes();
        }

        program.use();

        int uniTex = program.getUniformLocation("texImage");
        program.setUniform(uniTex, 0);

        /* Upload the new vertex data */
        vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
        vbo.uploadSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, vertices);

        /* Draw batch */
        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, numVertices);

        /* Clear vertex data for next batch */
        vertices.clear();
        numVertices = 0;
    }
}
```

This is how I setup the VAO, VBO, and shaders:

```
private void setupShaders() {
    if (!main.isLegacy()) {
        /* Generate Vertex Array Object */
        vao = new VertexArrayObject();
        vao.bind();
    } else {
        vao = null;
    }

    /* Generate Vertex Buffer Object */
    vbo = new VertexBufferObject();
    vbo.bind(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);

    /* Create FloatBuffer */
    vertices = MemoryUtil.memAllocFloat(4096);

    /* Upload null data to allocate storage for the VBO */
    long size = vertices.capacity() * Float.BYTES;
    vbo.uploadData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, size, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    /* Initialize variables */
    numVertices = 0;

    /* Load shaders */
    Shader vertexShader, fragmentShader;
    if (!main.isLegacy()) {
        vertexShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "resources/shaders/vertex.txt");
        fragmentShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "resources/shaders/fragment.txt");
    } else {
        vertexShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, "resources/shaders/legacyVertex.txt");
        fragmentShader = Shader.loadShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, "resources/shaders/legacyFragment.txt");
    }

    /* Create shader program */
    program = new ShaderProgram();
    program.attachShader(vertexShader);
    program.attachShader(fragmentShader);
    if (!main.isLegacy()) {
        program.bindFragmentDataLocation(0, "fragColor");
    }
    program.link();
    program.use();

    /* Delete linked shaders */
    vertexShader.delete();
    fragmentShader.delete();

    /* Get width and height of framebuffer */
    long window = GLFW.glfwGetCurrentContext();
    int width, height;
    try (MemoryStack stack = MemoryStack.stackPush()) {
        IntBuffer widthBuffer = stack.mallocInt(1);
        IntBuffer heightBuffer = stack.mallocInt(1);
        GLFW.glfwGetFramebufferSize(window, widthBuffer, heightBuffer);
        width = widthBuffer.get();
        height = heightBuffer.get();
    }

    /* Specify Vertex Pointers */
    specifyVertexAttributes();

    /* Set texture uniform */
    int uniTex = program.getUniformLocation("texImage");
    program.setUniform(uniTex, 0);

    /* Set model matrix to identity matrix */
    Matrix4f model = new Matrix4f();
    int uniModel = program.getUniformLocation("model");
    program.setUniform(uniModel, model);

    /* Set view matrix to identity matrix */
    Matrix4f view = new Matrix4f();
    int uniView = program.getUniformLocation("view");
    program.setUniform(uniView, view);

    /* Set projection matrix to an orthographic projection */
    Matrix4f projection = Matrix4f.orthographic(0f, width, 0f, height, -1f, 1f);
    int uniProjection = program.getUniformLocation("projection");
    program.setUniform(uniProjection, projection);
}
```

Also a few questions about OpenGL in general:

Should I bind textures every frame, or bind/unbind them whenever they are on/off screen?

Should I have one VAO for everything, or one VAO for the same textures?

Looking at the tutorial, my code is literally all the same, the only difference is that I store textures in an array and draw them every frame instead of having a draw method called every frame elsewhere. In going to inprove on this system and whatever but for now this is a good render engine for my project.

looking into it, textures are supposed to be bound every frame and VAIs are best with the same frames.

Comment: That might be it, I was messing around with the code earlier.